# Show error while build ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

First time the build executed successfully. if i did same in second time its showing the error (After restart my system its working fine for first time only.) anybody do need full for me.

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.838 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugAssets'.
> Executor Singleton not started

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

E:\xampp\htdocs\Apps\trukr\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "E:\xampp\htdocs\Apps\trukr\platf
orms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b E:\xampp\htdocs\Apps\trukr\platforms\andro
id\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Screenshot :https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBOBW.png

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. it may help

```
ionic platform remove android
ionic platform add android
```